# android assign one of two string variables into one string in another class

Tags: android, url, onclicklistener

I have 2 classes. in first one I have 2 button and 2 string.two button starts same class. but if user press first button I want to send first string into second class's string. if choose other one I want to send second string.

Main Class

```
public String sendedUrl;
String url = "xxx";
String url2="yyy";

  imageViews[0].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            sendedUrl=url;
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Second.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
    imageViews[1].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            sendedUrl = url2;
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Second.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Second Class

```
MainActivity main = new MainActivity();
String Url;
Url = main.sendedUrl;
```

Comment: So what's error you are facing ?

Comment: Please search SO before posting new question :)

Answer (score 2):

When you creating an instance of a class the members of this class are set to `null` if you have not assigned any value to that particular member of that class.

You can make this member `static` or you can use

```
intent.putExtra("StringName");
```

to pass this member to other activity.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Bundle` to passing values like:

```
imageViews[0].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            sendedUrl=url;
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Second.class);
            intent.putExtra("strUrl", url);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
    imageViews[1].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            sendedUrl = url2;
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Second.class);
            intent.putExtra("strUrl", url2);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Inside your `Second Activity` in `OnCreate()`:

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras(); 
String url= extras.getString("strUrl");
```

Answer (score 0):

If Main and Second class are Activities u can pass URL intent. e.g

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this,Second.class);
intent.putExtra("URL",url)//url2 on 2nd button click
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

and get URL in Second Activity

```
Intent  intent=getIntent();
String URL=intent.getStringExtra("URL");
```